# Seaborn lineplot not plotting till the maximum value

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a dataframe with x-axis as the month and y-axis as the transaction amount. The amount column has a maximum value of around 8,000.

As there are around 12,000 records, there are multiple transactions on each day.

The code

```
s = sns.FacetGrid(df_time[df_time['movement']=='credit'],row='month',height=5,aspect=1.8)
s.map(sns.lineplot,'day','amount')
s.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.95)
s.fig.suptitle('Transaction amount(credit) with respect to day and month of the year', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Checking maximum value of amount in the dataframe

```
df_time[df_time['movement']=='credit'].amount.max()
```

Output: `8835.98`

This is the plot I got with seaborn lineplot.

[image]

The thing that I'm confused with is that the plot should go up-to around 8,000 as that is the maximum transaction value in my dataframe but instead it only goes upto 4,000 and gives me a solid plot as well as a shaded region.

What do these two forms of plots on the single plot indicate ?

Comment: Please provide you code. It's a bit hard to help you without seeing it (& sample of your data)

Comment: edited the question with more information

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn's lineplot by definition does not plot the maximum value. The value itself is aggregation of all y-values in the same x-value (e.g. mean). I guess you are asking about the "brighter" area around the line.

It's called confidence interval. It has a [mathematical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) and a way to compute it.
It's not the maximal and minimal value. Therefore it should not plot the maximal value anyway.